# Recursive call of flask application makes thread block

Tags: python, flask

I came across the issue where I was required to make an HTTP request inside of a flask application against the same flask application.

```
@app.route('/endpoint1')
def endpoint1():
    requests.get('http://localhost:5000/endpoint2')
    ...

@app.route('/endpoint2')
def endpoint2():
    ...
```

The server became blocked.

Comment: a better design would be to call endpoint2 directly, there's no need to issue an internal request like this, or use the requests library within flask at all.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you just call the method?

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that Flask runs on just one thread, by default. I solved the issue above by simply making the application multi-threaded by adding the `threaded` parameter.

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```